# Business Catalyst Product Search and Results

Tags: business-catalyst

Using the business catalyst search feature seems to return results with an or function, so that any item that meets any criteria is displayed as a result.  Is there any way to change this to an and function, so that only the items that meet all the criteria will be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by doing a product list dump that cancels the template to get all the data on the page without displaying anything. Then used liquid/json to label products in divs according to what is in their names and added an isotope filter for sorting.

http://revivalfloatspa.businesscatalyst.com/producttest

Example code:

```
{module_productlistdump catalogId="-1" sortType="Alphabetical" template ="" collection="book"}
{% for item in book.items %}
    {% capture Pname %}
    {{item.name}}
    {% endcapture %}
        {% if Pname contains 'Massage' %}
            {% if Pname contains '9AM' %} 
                <div class="color-shape tall 9AM purple massage">
                <p><a href=" {{ item.url }} "> {{item.name}}</a></p></div>
            {% elsif Pname contains '10AM' %}
                <div class="color-shape tall 10AM purple massage">
                <p><a href=" {{ item.url }} "> {{item.name}}</a></p></div>
            {% endif %}
        {% elsif Pname contains 'Float' %}
            {% if Pname contains '9AM' %} 
                <div class="color-shape tall 9AM purple float">
                <p><a href=" {{ item.url }} "> {{item.name}}</a></p></div>
            {% elsif Pname contains '10AM' %}
                <div class="color-shape tall 10AM purple float">
                <p><a href=" {{ item.url }} "> {{item.name}}</a></p></div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

requires jquery and isotope.